# Should I give users the ability to 'unreport' on a forum

Tags: programming-practices, laravel, forum

(I really hope this is the appropriate place for a question like this. Nevertheless, I hope some of you can give me your opinions, regardless).

I am building a forum with Laravel. Progress has been great and I love how it is turning out.

I have just added the ability for users to report topics and posts. (Posts are replies to a single topic).

Everything is working fine; I just have a question about best practice.

Should the user have the ability to 'unreport' a post or topic that he or she has reported? Actually doing it is easy. I just wanted to hear some opinions from other people.

Eventually, moderators and administrators can manage posts and topics. They will be able to see which were reported and perform any actions in return (delete or update the post or topic).

Thank you in advance for any responses.

Comment: I think this is [more of a ux question](https://ux.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You may have more luck asking on the Webmasters stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to undo is very comforting to users.

Put me in an environment where I can bang on things without them breaking and I'll play around like an exploring child.

Put me in an environment where every mistake is set in stone and held up for the world to see and I'll sit in the corner and cry.

There are two good reasons I can imagine you'd even ask this question.

1. You're wondering if it's worth the effort to implement.

   - It is.
2. You're wondering if you're losing important information.

   - You don't have to be.  You can log what happened privately.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, Orange. I have already implemented it.

I guess I shouldn't even worry about logging them, either. I am sure that a user will not want to unreport something when he or she has already reported it.

Comment: By the way: Stackexchange does allow to retract flags. I just checked it on this answer.

Comment: @Philipp if you want to make an issue of it take it to meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @CandiedOrange I am not making an issue of it.